# Is possible to add a field to content moderation's states?

Tags: workflows

I'm on D 9.4.x and using content moderation module.

Is possible to add a custom field to the states of the workflows\module?

E.g. add a boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box? No.

You will have to create a custom module that adds such boolean field to your content types or entity types.

Via `hook_form_alter` you can use `#ajax` with `#access` OR alternatively use `#states` to show/hide the field when a different moderation state is selected.

Comment: Probably I was not clear, I'm trying to add the field to the state itself, e.g. to the `draft` state. The problem I'm facing it's that the code I found in internet about isn't working. I don't know if the reason is because the `core/modules/workflows/src/StateInterface.php` doesn't extends any other of the "entity" interfaces, or else.

Comment: @Giuseppe That is because content moderation state is not a [fieldable entity](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/field-api/making-an-entity-fieldable)